# Can't push or fetch with git

Tags: git, github

I can pull but I can't push or fetch using git version 1.9.5. It suddenly started giving me the following error. Any ideas as to how to fix it?

```
$ git fetch 
fatal: unable to access 'https://arubygit@github.com/webpeak/wp-cla-dcs.git/':error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Comment: Try updating to a newer git version perhaps? The string "tlsv1" in there could be an indicator that github has stopped supporting older TLS versions (as they should - https://payment-services.ingenico.com/int/en/ogone/support/products/tls) and that your git version doesn't support anything higher.

Answer (score 4):

You are likely running into an incompatibility with GitHub's deprecation of weak encryption protocols.  You can see list of incompatible clients and potential solutions here:

https://githubengineering.com/crypto-removal-notice/