# fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg.git/': Peer reports incompatible or unsupported protocol version

Tags: angularjs, git, jenkins, github, bower-install

I am facing this issue in jenkins when i run bower install --allow-root. The build fails displaying the following error:
**Failed to execute "git ls-remote --tags --heads
https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg.git**

final build failure error displays as follows:

**fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/gabelerner/canvg.git/': Peer reports incompatible or unsupported protocol version**

It shows the same error with different GIT file paths.

**Previous error was :
Error fetching remote repo 'origin'**

which we solved changing the SSH key.

If we remove bower install command from the build, the build is successful.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 36):

This may be the reason to your problem: 
[Discontinue support for weak cryptographic standards](https://githubengineering.com/crypto-deprecation-notice/)

> ....As a result, GitHub is announcing the immediate deprecation, and
>   eventual disablement, of our use of the following cryptographic
>   standards:
>
> TLSv1/TLSv1.1 - This applies to all HTTPS connections, including web,
>   API, and git connections to https://github.com and
>   https://api.github.com. diffie-hellman-group1-sha1 - This applies to
>   all SSH connections to github.com. diffie-hellman-group14-sha1 - This
>   applies to all SSH connections to github.com. All of the above will be
>   disabled on February 1, 2018.

so you need to upgrade to stronger ciphers.
I see that this solution helped others
[github-unable-to-access-ssl-connect-error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938385/github-unable-to-access-ssl-connect-error)

```
yum update -y nss curl libcurl
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanks! Some of the yum mirrors throw me the same error when I am trying to do yum update! Luckily some of them still allow the older one.

Answer (score 4):

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/john/git-Training.git/': Peer reports incompatible or unsupported protocol version.

I upgraded to the newest cipher, the fatal error was gone.

```
[john@doe git-Training]$ sudo yum update -y nss curl libcurl
```