# OpenSSL: error tlsv1 alert protocol version

Tags: openssl, protocols, wget, ubuntu-10.04

We have some legacy code and hence need to perform few things on `ubuntu-10.04 amd64`. I am trying to download a `'gperftools-2.6.90.tar.gz'`. file.

```
wget https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/releases/download/gperftools-2.6.90/gperftools-2.6.90.tar.gz
```

Error message

```
--2020-02-20 23:33:39--  https://github.com/gperftools/gperftools/releases/download/gperftools-2.6.90/gperftools-2.6.90.tar.gz
Resolving github.com... 140.82.118.4
Connecting to github.com|140.82.118.4|:443... connected.
OpenSSL: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
Unable to establish SSL connection
```

I also tried using curl and displayed the same error.

It appears to be a a protocol issue but not sure of fixing it / work around ?

Comment: Dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48938385/github-unable-to-access-ssl-connect-error and more. Github stopped supporting the obsolete protocols used by Ubuntu 10 (???!!!) two years ago. Download on some other system that isn't massively obsolete and then transfer to your target.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 I need to compile many things and gperftools is one among them. I am actually panning to write a bash script and share the script with rest of my peers. It have tried transferring the package manually  to the test bash script and it looked good. The only outstanding task is to download gperftools.

Comment: I have also tried to get it from source forge - https://sourceforge.net/projects/gperftools.mirror/   . But it has the same error.

Comment: [google sourceforge TLS 1.0 support first hit](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/site-support/17088/) says they also dropped it two years ago. Over the last few years _many_ public websites did, and many that haven't yet probably will soon. (Stack just did so a few weeks ago -- if you try to connect to SO or SX from your Ubuntu 10 that won't work either. But a bash script is also a file -- if you can transfer a bash script to the target, why can't you transfer the gperftools file? Or run your own obsolete server, or a proxy like nginx/haproxy/varnish that can do TLS1.0 down and 1.1+ up.

Answer (score -2):

Ensure that your internet connection is stable and it should work fine. Also try updating your Ubuntu version to the latest one (20.04.2.0 LTS)

Comment: How does this help solve an issue on Ubuntu? I.e. Linux. I don't think windows binaries from some random site are going to help.

Comment: This still doesn't work on WSL/Ubuntu with wget 1.20.3